# Which database type is applicable to Android application for contents available in server?

Tags: android, database

I am trying to develop a real-time Android application where all contents are stored in server. So, they are available whenever a connection to Internet is available. Also, the application provides communication between users and conversations are stored in the server as well. Nothing is locally stored.
However, I am still cannot decide which database type I can use. I intended to use SQLite but I am not sure if I can really use it or not.
Could you please guide me to the proper database type to my application.
Appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: your database wont matter if you are using a webservice transfer data using json , xml etc ... so it wont matter what db you are using in context to android

Comment: Also if everything is stored in server anyway, why not just use in-memory data structures?

Comment: Thanks droidhot and Kostas. I used MySQL with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As its upto you which database you use.

you may Install Lamp (For Linux) or WAMP(for window) . This is a nice database tool and very easy to handle and easy linked  with PHP for various database function

Comment: Thanks Rajendra, I used XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed something similar to what you are talking about and here is what I would suggest you to go for.

Use **SQL server** to manage the data on your desktop and create a **web-service in .Net** on Visual Studio.

*(Note that as others have already mentioned, it really does not matter what is the database you are using in your server end, because eventually the data is going to come to the Android application from the server in form of either xml or json in the web-service., regardless of what database you are using. So it is totally your wish which database you want to use.)*

Then connect to the **web-service** in your application and set/get data from the remote Database, using **SOAP**.

[Link](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx) on how to make a web-service in .NET (does not include the implementation in Android).

Links on how to connect your service with Android : [this](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap) and [this](http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html).